# Using Local IP address In a Mule ESB application

Tags: networking, localhost, ip-address, mule, esb

I've deployed a Mule ESB application which accept as input a GET HTTP request as follow

```
http://localhost:8088/esb/?id=xxx
```

when replace the `localhost` with my local IP adress `192.168.1.2` it doesnt work neither on my machin nor on another one from my lan.
I've added a rule in the firewall to allow the port 8088 and it doesn't work either.
I've disabled my antivirus and the firewall and no result.
could someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have absolutely no problem using this endpoint configuration:

```
<http:inbound-endpoint
    address="http://192.168.1.68:8088/esb"
    exchange-pattern="request-response" />
```

Mule (3.4.0) correctly binds to my IP address and the `8088` port.

So please update your question with the config that shows how you've configured your inbound HTTP endpoint.

Comment: I've totally forget about the inbound HTTP component, 
Now I changed the localhost to my local ip address and it's working now.
thank you so much.