# Mule http end point replace localhost with server ip does not work

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I was testing a service on my local machine and it works fine with localhost. When I replace it with the server IP and deploy on the host server it doesnt work. I tried changing the IP to my PC's network (WAN) ip and it still doesnt work.

```
<flow name="commonFlow1" doc:name="commonFlow1">
     <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"     host="http://172.20.10.3" port="8083" path
```

Only when host is localhost above it works.

Is there anyother parameter I need to set?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a URI in the host parameter, it should be just the IP address:

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
      host="172.20.10.3" port="8083" ...
```

Note that it's easier to bind to all network interfaces with `0.0.0.0`, that way your application can be deployed on any host without having to configure the IP:

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
      host="0.0.0.0" port="8083" ...
```

Comment: cool, is mule using something from CommonsIO for that 0.0.0.0 case?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at: [Using Local IP address In a Mule ESB application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796003/using-local-ip-address-in-a-mule-esb-application) (replacinghost + port with adress parameter)